# How to project only part of a texture to a face threejs?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I want to make portals with threejs by drawing an ellipse and then texture mapping a WebGlRenderTarget to its face. I have that function sort of working, but it tries to stretch the large rectangular buffer from the render target to the ellipse. What I want is to project the texture in its original dimensions onto the ellipse and just cut out anything that doesn't hit the ellipse like so:

Before Projection:

[image]

After projection:

[image]

How can this be done with threejs?
I've looked into texture coordinates, but don't understand how to use them, and even saw a projection light PR in threejs that might work?

Edit: I also watched a Sebastian Lague video on portals and saw he does this with “screen space coordinates”. Any advice on using those?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a codepen available here:
https://codepen.io/cdeep/pen/JjyjOqY

UV mapping lets us specify which parts of the texture correspond to which vertices of the geometry. More details here: https://www.spiria.com/en/blog/desktop-software/understanding-uv-mapping-and-textures/

You could loop through the vertices and set the corresponding UV value.

```js
const vertices = ellipseGeometry.attributes.position.array;
for(let i = 0; i < numPoints; i++) {
  const [x, y] = [vertices[3*i], vertices[3*i + 1]];
  uvPositions.push(0.5 + x * imageHeight / ((2 * yRadius) * imageWidth));
  uvPositions.push(0.5 + y / (2 * yRadius));
}
ellipseGeometry.setAttribute("uv", new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(uvPositions, 2 ));
```

UV coordinates increase from (0, 0) to (1, 1) from bottom left to top right.
The above code works because the ellipse is on the x-y plane. Or else, you'll need to get the x,y values in the plane of the ellipse.

More info on texture mapping in three.js here:
https://discoverthreejs.com/book/first-steps/textures-intro/

Edit: Do note that the demo doesn't really look like a portal. For that, you'll need to move the texture based on the camera view which isn't that simple

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed answer! What is the number 240 from in uvPositions.push ?

Comment: Ohhh I changed 240 to my x and y radius for my ellipse and now everything looks great!

Comment: Yes. It's the height of the ellipse. I'll edit the answer

Comment: How would you recommend getting the x,y values in the plane of the ellipse?

Comment: x is the dot product of vector representing the position of a point with unit vector in the direction of the minor axis. Same for y with the major axis. You will need to know the direction of major and minor axes.  
Based on your application, If you know one of these axes, it's easy to get the other by a cross product with the face normal vector for the ellipse. If not, I don't know of a way to get these vectors

Comment: Minor clarification: x is the dot product of vector representing the position of a point with unit vector in the direction of the minor axis...... both of which are relative to the center of the ellipse

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'll try that out